# jide oss 3.1.1, missing checkboxlistselectionmodel?

Tags: java, swing, jide

I am using the Jide OSS 3.1.1

while using the CheckBoxList, I find that it's missing the getCheckBoxListSectionModel? It's in the documentation but the dot operator reveals no such thing. I'm wonder if this is available only in the paid version??

There is `getSelectionModel()` however using this will not fire the selected event.

```
    Object[] options = {"This Element","Similar Elements"};
            CheckBoxListWithSelectable checkboxlist = new CheckBoxListWithSelectable(options);
            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, checkboxlist, 
                       "Please Select Action(s) For This Element", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

            checkboxlist.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("selected");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Yes, the method is on CheckBoxList. CheckBoxListWithSelectable is the first version we created for the check box list. It uses its element (must implement Selectable interface) in the ListModel to store the selection information, v.s CheckBoxList stores it in a ListSelectionModel. We decided to keep both designs as both are useful in certain cases.

Thanks Max for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this method just fine in older version (2.10.*). But looking at the depot for 3.1.1, it is there in the [source](http://java.net/projects/jide-oss/sources/svn/content/branches/trunk_3.1.1/src/com/jidesoft/swing/CheckBoxList.java?rev=2050).

Also, you have it misspelled in your question. I hope you're looking for [`getCheckBoxListSelectionModel`()](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/swing/CheckBoxList.html#getCheckBoxListSelectionModel%28%29).

Comment: figured it out i have to use just CheckBoxList not the whole :withSelectable"....by does Jide OSS expire after 30 days?